# How does realloc work regarding increasing size of memory blocks?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, sizeof, realloc

So how (and if) does realloc increase the memory pointed to in this loop.

```
char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));
ssize_t size = 0;

while(true)
{   
    //increment size;
    size++;

    // increment buffer_inc memory size by size (one byte at a time)
    buffer = realloc(buffer, size);
    ......
```

When I run this, I get that my inital `sizeof(buffer)` is `8` and after the loop, my size is still `8` shouldnt it be `9`?

What's weird is that even if I do `buffer = realloc(buffer, size + sizeof(char);` I still get that my value on `sizeof(buffer)` (after the loop) is `8` am I missing something regarding how realloc works? In my understanding it allocated more memory, in the amount of `size_t size`(passed as the second argument) for the memory passed in `void* ptr` (as the first argument).

Am I misunderstanding how realloc works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: Am I misunderstanding how realloc works?

A: *No*, but you are misunderstanding what you are printing!

---

**You are printing the size of the *pointer*.**

> So, for a 32bit computer, the pointer size can be 4 bytes; 64bit computers can have 8 bytes. Or, a 64bit computer running a 32bit OS will have 4 bytes. Still, under a specific architecture, all types of pointers (void*, int*, char*, long* etc) will have same size (except function pointers).

Check this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
        char* buf1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
        printf("buf1 = %zu\n", sizeof(buf1));
        char* buf2 = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
        printf("buf2 = %zu\n", sizeof(buf2));
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~/Desktop$ ./a.out 
buf1 = 8
buf2 = 8
```

---

You can't print how much memory you have allocated. It's the *programmer's responsibility* to keep track of the memory (s)he has allocated, by keeping an extra variable, `size` in your example.

Comment: Alright, this made it so much clearer. How would I go about to print out how much memory I have allocated then?

Comment: @FelixRosén you cannot, see my update. Good question btw, I had the same when I was learning C, +1.

Comment: C and memory management at its best @FelixRosén! You will learn *a lot*, trust me! Glad I helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not misunderstanding `realloc`. You are misunderstanding `sizeof`.

`sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the pointer (which for you it seems to be 8), not the size of the buffer it points to. Yo will have to track the allocated size for yourself.